# Operator new in Kotlin (syntax)

Tags: java, kotlin

I get along with Java's **new** operator. It's pretty much simple:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
```

So we assume that this is a final variable. We don't want to change this particular variable.

In kotlin I should write something like:

```
val boundsBuilder: LatLngBounds.Builder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
```

which is pretty much the same. So I thought, maybe there is some way to make the thing **shorter**?

My java to kotlin konverter died, so I'm asking here.

Comment: `val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.Builder()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
```

The type will be inferred by Kotlin to be `LatLngBounds.Builder`, and you get to save some space.